# UpdatePanel not working in default document

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

My simple application has one page Default.aspx.

If I hit the page at /app/default the page loads and everything works. If i go to /app/ with no file name the page loads but my button does not work.

looking in fiddler I can see a working request starts like

> 1|#||4|219|updatePanel|MainContent_upDemo|

but a bad request returns the page starting with  and the updatepanel javascript can't parse it.

Turning off friendly URLs has the same issue but I now have to go to /app/Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CasualFrontEnd._Default" EnableEventValidation="true" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="EAV" Assembly="EAV" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCasual" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTesting" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnApply" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" Text="Apply" OnClick="BtnApply_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Do you really need to use this dead tech?

Comment: I'm totally with you but I'm updating a 7 year old application based on old controls and I don't have time to rewire in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the way the default path is handled with no route.

my solution:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("nofile", "", "~/Default.aspx");
    //var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Temporary;
    //routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
}
```